# NameError: name 'myconf' is not defined

Tags: python

I am working on web2py image blog.

I am unable to understand these errors:

> Internal error
>
> Ticket issued: images/127.0.0.1.2016-11-22.16-44-39.95144250-6a2e-4648-83f9-aa55873e6ae8
>
> Error ticket for "images"
>   Ticket ID
>   127.0.0.1.2016-11-22.16-44-39.95144250-6a2e-4648-83f9-aa55873e6ae8
>
> type 'exceptions.NameError'> name 'myconf' is not defined
>
> Version
>   web2py™    Version 2.14.6-stable+timestamp.2016.05.10.00.21.47
>   Python Python 2.7.12: /usr/bin/python (prefix: /usr)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/sonu/Software/web2py /gluon/restricted.py", line 227, in restricted
>       exec ccode in environment
>
> File "/home/sonu/Software/web2py /applications/images/models/menu.py", line 17, in 
>       response.meta.author = myconf.get('app.author')
>   NameError: name 'myconf' is not defined

Comment: what you did until now? post your code..

Comment: The error is pretty self-descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

This post seems to be discussed here.
[resolved/work around](https://github.com/web2py/web2py-book/issues/318)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this very same problem as follows:

I removed `models/menu.py`, and then the problem appears to be solved.

=> Remeber delete the `models/menu.py`